# JFileChooser open multiple files in the order they are clicked

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, look-and-feel

I have an application that takes multiple files and applies some operation that depends on their order (e.g. merge them one after another).

The user can select files in any order by Ctrl+click, or by Shift+click.

The list files returned by the chooser does not have the same order as the user clicked them. I'd like them to be returned in the same order the user clicked them.

Disclaimer: I'm "the user"

I'm using the `JFileChooser` class with Java look and feel on Windows 7 64bits, with JDK 7.

Here's a minimal example

```
package choosertest;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ChooserTest extends JFrame {

    JFileChooser chooser;

    public ChooserTest() {
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        testOpen();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChooserTest();
    }

    private void testOpen() {
        int choice = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            File[] inputFiles = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
            for (File f: inputFiles) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Afaik, that's not possible. You have to use subsequent calls to FileChooser, resulting in multiple Dialogs. Another approach would be to select all files in the FileChooser, and offer a method to sort them in your UI (which would be more user friendly, imho)

Comment: For power users, selecting an entry and clicking up and down arrows takes more time. Plus, I get quite disappointed when the interface thinks it knows better. If I click files in an order, I don't want you to sort them. Mkay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the point that it Ctrl+click works and Shift+click selecting files "downwards" works.

However, using Shift+click to select files "upwards" still adds files in the wrong order, which can be confusing.

Moreover, this solution does not update the "File name" text field to reflect the actual order of the selection. It may be possible to "fix" this using reflection, though.

[image: File name text field]

If you need a quick solution to select files in the correct order by Ctrl-clicking them, this works just fine (both select and deselect).

```
package choosertest;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ChooserTest extends JFrame {

    File[] selected;
    JFileChooser chooser;

    public ChooserTest() {
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        testOpen();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChooserTest();
    }

    private void testOpen() {

        chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("SelectedFilesChangedProperty")) {
                    if (selected == null) {
                        selected = (File[]) evt.getNewValue();
                    } else {
                        File[] newSelection = (File[]) evt.getNewValue();

                        if (newSelection == null) {
                            selected = null;
                        }
                        // check back and forth to preserve the order of files
                        // as the user added them
                        else {
                            List<File> orderedSel = new LinkedList<>();

                            // add files that are still selected
                            for (File f : selected) {
                                for (File f2 : newSelection) {
                                    if (f.equals(f2)) {
                                        orderedSel.add(f);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            Arrays.sort(selected);
                            // add newly selected files
                            for (File f : newSelection) {
                                if (Arrays.binarySearch(selected, f) < 0) {
                                    orderedSel.add(f);
                                }
                            }

                            selected = orderedSel.toArray(
                                    new File[orderedSel.size()]);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(selected)); //debug
                }
            }
        });

        // copy previous array of selected files
        File[] prevSelected = null;
        if (selected != null) {
            prevSelected = new File[selected.length];
            System.arraycopy( selected, 0, prevSelected, 0, selected.length );
        }

        int choice = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

        // if the user did not cancel the selection
        if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("FINAL selection: " + Arrays.toString(selected)); //debug
        } else {
            // restore the previous selection
            selected = prevSelected;
            System.out.println("PREVIOUS selection: " + Arrays.toString(selected)); //debug
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than ordering the files based upon selection order in a JFileChooser, you might consider re-ordering the files after selection using something like a JTable/JList. Be that as it may, you might be able to plug into the listener system of a JFileChooser to get the selection order by adding a PropertyChangeListener to the JFileChooser. Whenever a File is selected, the 'SelectedFilesChangedProperty' is fired, and PropertyChangeEvent.getNewValue() should return the selected files

```
    final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    chooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ( evt.getPropertyName().equals("SelectedFilesChangedProperty") ){
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString((File[])evt.getNewValue()));
            }
        }
    });
```

You would need to check the array of Files returned by getNewValue() to see which new file was selected (or deselected) to maintain order.

Comment: The field listing the names of the selected files would need to be changed as well, to reflect the click-order being preserved. Can make it do that without spawning extra events?

Comment: You would probably have to recurse through the component hierarchy of the JFileChooser to find the JTextField and set its text manually

Comment: Bracket fixed (was an edit mistake). This code works for me - how are you adapting this into your code? Did you place the JFileChooser instance into a JFrame, or better yet call showDialog on the instance?

Comment: Multiple selection with Ctrl+click is not recognized if Ctrl is kept pressed, and stops working after some clicks.

Comment: See the edit to my answer - use the SelectedFilesChangedProperty (note the s after Files), and getNewValue returns an array of Files

Comment: Nice, thanks. What about changing the field showing the names of the selected files without triggering more `propertyChange` events?

Comment: Did you try it? Changing the text field manually does not fire any SelectedFilesChangedProperty  events, so I'd presume changing it programmatically would not do so either.

Comment: I'm worried it would trigger some events i don't know about. If you say it's safe, I'll give it a try. BTW if you implemented the full logic for the click order, this answer could be more useful, IMHO.

Comment: @Agostino, `BTW if you implemented the full logic for the click order...,` - that is for you to do. We are not here to write the code for you, only point you in the right direction. Then once you solve the problem with completed code you can post it on the forum for the benefit of others. That way you also contribute to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Modified above code to show in selection order in the text field

```
/*
 * FileName  :SelectedOrderedFileChooser.java
 */

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI;

/**
 * File Chooser with selection order<br>
 * Only work for Ctrl + click selection
 */
public class SelectedOrderedFileChooser extends JFileChooser{

    /** Selection order file name list */
    private List<String> selectedFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    boolean isSelectionOrder = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public SelectedOrderedFileChooser() {
        super();
        setSelectionOrder(false);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param aIsSelectionOrder Selection ordered or not<br>
     * true : Selection order, false : File Name order(JFileChooser Default)
     */
    public SelectedOrderedFileChooser(boolean aIsSelectionOrder) {
        super();
        setSelectionOrder(aIsSelectionOrder);
    }
    /**
     * Get selected file names in selection order
     * @param fs Selected files
     * @return File names in selection order
     */
    private List<String> getFileNamesInSelectionOrder(File[] fs) {
        List<String> tmpSelectedFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> tmpResultFileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File f : fs) {
            // Get all current selected file names
            tmpSelectedFileNames.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        for (String fn : selectedFileNames) {
            if (tmpSelectedFileNames.contains(fn)) {
                // If ordered selected file name is in current selected file names, add to temporary file name list
                tmpResultFileNames.add(fn);
            }
        }

        // If there are current selected file names that is not in temporary file name list, add them
        for (String fn : tmpSelectedFileNames) {
            if (tmpResultFileNames.contains(fn) == false) {

                tmpResultFileNames.add(fn);
            }
        }
        return tmpResultFileNames;
    }

    /**
     * Get selected file names
     * @return Selected file names
     */
    public List<String> getSelectedFileNames() {
        return selectedFileNames;
    }

    /**
     * Is selection order or not?
     * @return true : Selection order, false : File Name order(JFileChooser Default)
     */
    public boolean isSelectionOrder() {
        return isSelectionOrder;
    }

    /**
     * Set whether file selection order or not.
     * @param aIsSelectionOrder true : Selection order, false : File Name order(JFileChooser Default)
     */
    public void setSelectionOrder(boolean aIsSelectionOrder) {
        this.isSelectionOrder = aIsSelectionOrder;
        this.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ( evt.getPropertyName().equals("SelectedFilesChangedProperty") ){
                    File[] fs = (File[])evt.getNewValue();
                    if (null != fs && fs.length > 0) {
                        if (isSelectionOrder) {
                             // If selection order、get file name in selection order and set to selected order file name list
                            List<String> tmpResultFileNames = getFileNamesInSelectionOrder(fs);
                            selectedFileNames = tmpResultFileNames;
                            showTextField();
                        } else {
                            // If not selection order、FileChooser default order
                            selectedFileNames.clear();
                            for (File f : fs) {
                                selectedFileNames.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get selection ordered files in array
     * @return selection ordered files in array
     */
    public File[] getSelectedOrderedFiles() {
        List<File> ret = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (String fName : selectedFileNames) {
            File f = new File(fName);
            ret.add(f);
        }
        return ret.toArray(new File[ret.size()]);
    }

    /**
     * Show file names in selection order in text field of JFileChooser
     */
    public void showTextField(){
        try {
            String res = "";
            for (File f : getSelectedOrderedFiles()) {
                res += "\"" + f.getName() + "\" ";
            }
            MetalFileChooserUI ui = (MetalFileChooserUI)this.getUI();
            Field field;
            field = MetalFileChooserUI.class.getDeclaredField("fileNameTextField");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            JTextField tf = (JTextField) field.get(ui);
            tf.setText(res.trim());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work or is better than the existing solutions. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If I understand correctly, the improvement is that it shows the file names in the "File name" field. I'm not sure if it updates the list of names correctly (can't test this now), but it sure shows the effort.